# After upgrading to Ubuntu 1310 I cannot used a period

Tags: keyboard, 13.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 1310 and now the period doesn't work on my keyboard Does anyone know how I can fix this? As always, I appreciate any feedback I receive, thank you for all of your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it just the period key that's not working? if not then maybe going to `preferences > keyboard > Layout setting` and selecting the right keyboard layout would restore functionality to all keys.

Comment: Minos,yes it is only the period that I am having a problem with I did as you said and when to preferences The compose key and the alternative characters key settings are disabled However, I am not seeing a punctuation menu

Comment: Have you tried changing the layout and then reselecting the correct one?